# How can I get NetBeans to show me proper documentation for Java methods?

Tags: java, netbeans

Right now when I use a built in method, it shows me the returns types and nothing else that's useful.

Is there something I can download to make the info from the intellisense more robust?

> Javadoc not found. Either Javadoc
>   documentation for this item does not
>   exist or you have not added specified
>   Javadoc in the Java Platform Manager
>   or the Library Manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to download the JDK API docs, which you can get from [this page](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp#docs).
Then in NetBeans, go to `Tools -> Java Platforms -> Javadoc` to specify the directory where you downloaded them.

Comment: After I do that, can I freely delete the file from that location? Or do you recommend I move the file to a folder because it cannot be moved in the future without having to associate it again?

Comment: @Sergio: put the docs wherever you want them, but don't delete them. NetBeans just references the directory. I usually put them in the JDK directory.

Answer (score -1):

The javadocs come in the jdk package or at least in JDK 1.8. You can add the zip files named `src.zip` and `javafx-src.zip` to the tools>java platform>Javadoc.