# Netbeans says javadocs not found

Tags: netbeans, javadoc

I have some problems with Netbeans IDE.  I installed `v. 7.0.1`, but now the pop-up windows of the javadoc say:

```
Javadoc not found. Either Javadoc documentation for this item does not exist or 
you have not added specified Javadoc in the Java Platform Manager or the Library 
Manager.
```

Why didn't it auto-download the JavaDocs?  I'm talking about component, method etc etc.. of Java Platform SE.

Comment: Another thing to try: In the "projects" view of Netbeans, under "dependencies" subfolder you will see `.jar` files that provide the source code for your functionality, right click the `.jar` file and choose "Download JavaDocs" then clean build and try again.  This assumes your .jar files have builtin support for fetching their own javadocs locally.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Java Platforms

Select the platform that you want and go to the javadoc tab
and the url to the javadocs. either http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/ or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe JDK include javadoc in it But something went wrong either at the time of installation or later. So I solved this issue using these steps:
**Goto**

```
Tools >> Analyze Javadoc
```

An Analyzer tab will appear with the method/s that you defined and have no javadoc.
Select its checkbox and <kbd>Fix Selected</kbd> Button will enable press that button and problem is now gone.
In my case `removeAllRows()` is the method that has no javadoc.
For further check this image[image]

.
It does not create missing javadoc for your own methods **But** also fix javadoc  for predefined methods.
If this does not solve your problem than you should try adding javadoc manually.

Comment: NOTE:  Javadoc is not included in JDK.