# How to fix "Javadoc not found" message for ImageJ functions in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, imagej, fiji

I am using ImageJ functions on Netbeans and I added the ImageJ libraries/jar files to my project.  When I attempt to import these functions I get this message "Javadoc not found. Either Javadoc documentation for this item does not exist or you have not added specified Javadoc in the Java Platform Manager or the Library Manager."  This message only happens for ImageJ functions, not basic Java functions.  I believe that this is connected to the list of errors I get when I run code with ImageJ functions in it.

I read here [Netbeans says javadocs not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504572/netbeans-says-javadocs-not-found) that this issue could be fixed by adding a url to the Javadoc window.  I attempted to follow the instructions by adding several URLs of FIJI Javadocs that I found on google, but the error has not gone away.  Here are the URLs that I already tried adding: https://javadoc.scijava.org/ImgLib2/ https://javadoc.scijava.org/ImageJ/overview-summary.html https://javadoc.scijava.org/Fiji/

```
package learn;
import net.imagej.plugins.commands.io.newImage;
newImage("New Image","16-bit ramp", 800, 900, 1);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with ImageJ, but this may work: [1] In NetBeans, select **Tools > Libraries** [2] In the list of libraries on the left select the **ImageJ** library/jar you added. [3] Click the **Javadoc** tab, then click the **Add Zip/Folder...** button. [4] Navigate to your local download of the Javadoc zip for ImageJ, select it, and then click the **Add ZIP/Folder** button. [5] Click **OK** to close the Library Manager window and try using **Help** for some ImageJ method or class.

Comment: If that doesn't work then try asking on [ImageJ's forum](https://forum.image.sc/tags/imagej). Your question is probably off topic for Stack Overflow since the tag description for `imagej` states: _"Please consider asking ImageJ-specific questions on the Image.sc forum: https://forum.image.sc/. This tag should be used for questions about programming in/for ImageJ."_

Comment: You might also want to check out [this screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ac-6gJ2eRb0) about developing IJ plugins in NetBeans, if you haven't already. Be sure to add the maven.imagej.net repository in your project's pom.xml. As mentioned by @skomisa, ask on the image.sc forum for further help.