# Play framework 2.6.x documentation in NetBeans IDE after sbt "eclipse with-source"

Tags: netbeans, playframework, sbt, javadoc

Could someone tell me how I do to add the Play 2.6.x javadoc to my NetBeans 8.2 IDE. I only work with Java (8) and not Scala. This question is different from those already on this site, because i use "sbt eclipse" in a Terminal window to build the right ".classpath". After, in the IDE, i use the "Pleasure Play Framework Plugin" to open the Play framework project (source:
 http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/61050/pleasure-play-framework-plugin)

I've tried almost everything, but I can't have the javadoc (per example for the Play "ok" method). For some librairies, i can attach by hand a javadoc (for example for play.db.jpa in the .ivy2 cache), but not for the core play_2.12-2.6.x. But I have all sources and javadoc in this cache. By specifying an URL, this does not work too.

The problem : no javadoc (help) for core Play framework :
[image]

The project in NetBeans with the "pleasure" plugin :
[image]

In the .classpath file created by "sbt eclipse" :
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add javaDoc to my Java code in a NetBeans based project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872185/how-to-add-javadoc-to-my-java-code-in-a-netbeans-based-project)

Comment: No, but I have more detailed my question.

Comment: could you post the screenshot as well ?

Comment: I think there is a bug : the play_2.12-2.6.5-javadoc.jar is NOT javadoc but scaladoc !